# redirecting PHP resolving the roles

Tags: php

Good day,
I'm making a web site and I have a litte problem. When I log in a user, php code get's an information from database if he is a simple user or an admininistrator.

```
    <?php 
require("session.php");
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $user='';
    $log_control=false;
    $q="SELECT id,username,email,salt,password FROM users WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1";
    $q_par=array(':username'=>$_POST['user']);
    try{
        $statment=$dbh->prepare($q);
        $res=$statment->execute($q_par);
    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die("Can't execute query:" . $e->getMessage());
    }       
      $row=$statment->fetch();
      if($row) 
        { 
            $pswd_check=hash('sha256',
            $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($i=0;$i<65536;$i++) 
            {  $pswd_check=hash('sha256', $pswd_check . $row['salt']);  } 

            if($pswd_check===$row['password']) 
            {  $log_control=true; } 
            if($log_control) 
            {   
            $q="SELECT userrole FROM users WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1";

            $q_par=array(':username'=>$_POST['user']);
    try{
        $statment=$dbh->prepare($q);
        $res=$statment->execute($q_par);
    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die("Can't execute query:" . $e->getMessage());
    }   
    $role = $statment->fetchColumn();


                if($role=='U'){
                unset($row['salt']); 
                unset($row['password']);  
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
                header("Location: user.php"); 
                die("Redirecting to: user.php");
                }
                if($role=='S'){
                unset($row['salt']); 
                unset($row['password']);  
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
                header("Location: admin.php"); 
                die("Redirecting to: admin.php");
                }

            }else 
            {  
            echo '<div class="alert">Password or username is wrong!</div>';
                $user=htmlentities($_POST['user'],
                ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            } 
        }
        }  ?>
```

So, this is a part where I'm trying to log in a user. But in the other part of code in the same page, I'm trying to control if the user was alredy loged in or not. And in the same time, I'm trying to get an information if he is a user or if he is a administrator.
With this :

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ 
                if($_SESSION['userrole']=='U'){
                header("Location: user.php"); 
                }
                if($_SESSION['userrole']=='S'){         
        header("Location: admin.php"); 
        }}
?>
```

but when I get to this page again(after logging in), it does not redirecting me, it says that userrole is undefined and I have to log in again. What's the problem?

Comment: you probably forgot `session_start()`. That has to be executed on **EVERY** script that uses $_SESSION...

Comment: Where u define _SESSION['userrole']

Comment: what is a "web side"?

Comment: @MarcB when I put a session in the second scrypt with require("session.php") it says that session has been already started.

Comment: well, where in your first script do you actually have `$_SESSION['userrole']`? Nowhere... the only session value you DO set is `$_SESSION['user']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is very clear **Undefined variable**.

You did not defined this variable in your code:

```
$_SESSION['userrole']
```

Your session is working fine you just need to define roles where you have defined the **$_SESSION['user'].**

Comment: you mean $_SESSION['userrole']=$row?

Comment: yes, something like `$_SESSION['userrole'] = $row['role']`

Comment: @lemmy as mr heart mentioned